# My LED strip lights just went boom, how to diagnose?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

I live in a rented house (in singapore), where the master bedroom alone is fitted with a [pair of LED strip lights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvuQd.jpg), and about a month back, when we tried to turn it on, it went a (soft) boom, and hasnt turned on since.

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of event and have any idea how to fix? The owner consulted an electrician who wants SGD250 to replace the whole thing..

The odd thing is everything is duplicated, so I am not sure if both simultaneously went bust or is it something else that is common that I am not seeing.

My other concern is that if we go ahead with the replacement, it might just go boom again, this particular light has been in place for 6 months only..

Comment: That seems expensive, for such a small outlay in parts and time. However, I'm not in your market, so what do I know? Have you established that there is current getting to the transformers? If there is, are the transformers working? A cheap multimeter would answer these questions.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate the 250 is 100 for parts + 145 for labor according to their quote.. I have not confirmed either of those points yet.

Comment: If you're paying part or all, I'd get another quote. Even if 2 transformers are required (and I doubt it), that looks like it could be purchased for about SGD35 from an internet retailer like fasttech or gearbest. I'm guessing about your local economy, but if you add 50% for it being bought locally, the price still looks inflated.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate im paying up to 150 of it, so unless i can get it below that, doesnt help me. I was wondering if there were some chance i could fix this myself.. The fact that they are two and both stopped working at the same time felt odd to me..

Comment: Both failing at once is odd. It could be as simple as the switch or the breaker. After that, it's the transformers. Least likely is the led strip itself. If you want to take this on, you'll need a multimeter for diagnosis.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Verified that the LEDs are getting an input of DC 0V, while the transformers are getting an input of 240V AC. I suppose that proves that the transformers are busted..

Comment: Perfect! Get new transformers and you've saved a ton of money. Just match the voltage and current of the existing ones. (Or maybe get ones with slightly higher current -- described as watts or amps -- for a bit of a cushion.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Great, thanks. My owner tells me that these were installed just 6 months ago. Does that indicate a deeper problem as to why they failed early, and at the same time as well..

Comment: It's curious and mysterious that they failed at the same time, but given the low quality of some transformers out there, a 6 month lifespan is believable. If you put 2 more back and they fail quickly, then I'd start looking for deeper problems.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate ok tnx

Answer (score 1):

Typically, LED lights are Diodes which are sensitive to polarity (+ vs -) you can blow them if you connect incorrectly or if you over-power the circuit. Other than that, a LED strip is typically quite robust.

My guess is that the power source has blown, (since the leds will require a DC input. You can check this by connecting a 12v battery directly to the LED strip (do you have access to the led wires?)

Comment: You should mention to test them when the breakers are off.